# Webview Showing Black screen in Mobile Devices?

Tags: android, webview, screen

Am implementing one movie app. So take embeded youtube using iframe. It's working in large devices but in mobile devices it showing black screen after streaming? Please help me

```
this.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
this.webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
this.webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
this.webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
this.webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
this.webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
this.webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
String html = getHTML();
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

and:

```
public String getHTML1() {
    Log.d("trailer_2 HTML", "ok");
    String html1 = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport=target-densitydpi=device-dpi\"        content=\"width=320"
            + this.frame_width
            + ", height"
            + this.frame_height
            + ",initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no\"/>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body style=\" background:transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0\">"
            + "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border:0; width: 100%; height:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            + "H7Ht-m2QMDY"
            + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
            + "</iframe>\n";
    return html1;

}
```

In manifest i have mention `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

..thanks in advance

Comment: maybe the problem is that the embedded Youtube has some problem understanding what to do in small iframe

Comment: thanks..i have tried differnt ways but its not working.is webview working depend on density?

Answer (score 0):

ur phone need flash player support. And if u have flash player also it

will not display first time,u need to double tap on player then it will work. Instead of that

u  can use android native YouTube player APi. Its in beta version now ,but its working

awesome.

Comment: thanks..i dont knw android native YouTube player APi.can u explain ?

Comment: Yeah u can download this api from this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/,and it s also explains how to use in different ways (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)